# unable to fix '__curl_rule_01__' declared as an array with a negative size

Tags: ios, app-store, 64-bit, cocos2d-x, arm64

I have developed a game like bounce ball using cocos2d-x 2.2.3 and xcode 6.1.1. When i trying to build, i am getting the "'**curl_rule_01**' declared as an array with a negative size"  error. After changing

Architectures: Standard architectures(arm7,arm64)

Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s arm64.

Any advice?

Comment: Seems this is your case: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/when-update-to-xcode-5-1-an-error-occur---curl-rule-01---declared-as-an-array-with-a-negative-size/11953/2